# Rendering Empty Arrays/Objects with Mustache

Tags: javascript, mustache

Is it possible to render empty arrays or objects in Mustache if I'm passing these values automatically? For instance, I might use {{value}} where the value is an empty object or array. But I want to render the empty array like [], I don't want Mustache to try to iterate through it!

Answer (score 0):

Mustache is very very simplistic - you might want to look into Handlebars for more functionality.  That being said, `{{value}}{{^value}}[]{{/value}}` should do the trick!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This would work if the value would always be an array but it's sometimes an empty object or undefined etc. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: `{{^value}}` should capture an empty array or any falsey value (undefined is falsey).  An empty object is, by definition, truthy, but then again your example wouldn't work for when value is an object.  In that case you would `{{#value}}{{propName}}{{^propName}}"value.propName" is empty or doesn't exist{{/propName}}{{/value}}`... Mustache is a *logicless* template engine, so the data you send it has to be *well known*.  The situation you describe "value might be an object *or* a value *or* an array" is not one that mustache supports in any way shape or form